Fails to boot after boot repair
My computer(Ubuntu 22.04) fails to boot and instead enters emergency mode. It asks me to either press Enter for maintenance or Ctrl+D to continue. Unfortunately, I don’t recall the exact steps I’ve taken so far to troubleshoot the problem, but my most recent attempt was using the boot-repair tool.
At the moment, the screen displays an error message that says "[Failed] failed to..." (I’ve attached a screenshot for reference), and below that is my boot info file.
As I’m not very familiar with operating systems in general (though I am comfortable following instructions), I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to proceed from here to resolve this issue.
Thank you so much for your time and assistance!
Message on boot-repair completion:
The boot files of [sda7 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu.
Boot Info:
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                            [20241110_1309]
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
Failed to write lock '/dev/sda2': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sda2': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to write lock '/dev/sda5': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sda5': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Resource temporarily unavailable
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic
Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda7 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s
======================= Reinstall the grub2 of /dev/sda7 =======================
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda7 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/sda7 into the MBR of /dev/sda
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda7 grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda7 update-grub
Sourcing file /etc/default/grub' Sourcing file /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-124-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-124-generic
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg
Boot successfully repaired.
You can now reboot your computer.
The boot files of [sda7 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu.
============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================
=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (,msdos7)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:     /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:     /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:      

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts
                at sector 2048.
Operating System:  
Boot files:      

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Boot files:     /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub
                /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System:  
Boot files:      

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:    vfat
Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:     /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
                /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi

================================ 2 OS detected =================================
OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS on sda7
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 7 on sda2
================================ Host/Hardware =================================
CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)
===================================== UEFI =====================================
BIOS/UEFI firmware: F1(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0004,0000,0003,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(5,MBR,0x6e697373,0x30d72800,0xee000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002  ubuntu    HD(5,MBR,0x6e697373,0x30d72800,0xee000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* UEFI OS    HD(5,MBR,0x6e697373,0x30d72800,0xee000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0004* Hard Drive     BBS(HD,,0x0)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
Boot0005* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.27    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f115e,0x800,0xee83c8)AMBO
============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================
Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________
sda    : notGPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
sda7    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,    grub2,    grub-install,    grubenv-ok,    update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda8    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    bootmgr,    is-winboot, ntfs
sda2    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    bootmgr,    is-winboot, ntfs
sda3    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda5    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda7    : isnotESP,    fstab-without-efi,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda8    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda
sda2    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda
sda3    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda
sda5    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda
sda7    : not--sepboot,    with-boot,    fstab-without-boot,    not-sep-usr,    with--usr,    fstab-without-usr,    std-grub.d,    sda
sda8    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    sda
fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________
Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x9d1cdf6b
Boot    Start       End Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048    206847  204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2        206848  409806847  409600000 195.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3        409806848  819404799  409597952 195.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda4        819406846 1953521663 1134114818 540.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda5    1638612992 1953521663  314908672 150.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda6        819406848  835028991   15622144   7.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sda7        835031040 1247971327  412940288 196.9G 83 Linux
sda8    1247973376 1638598655  390625280 186.3G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 7.45 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x001f115e
Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 15633351 15631304  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________
sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA WDC WD10EZEX-08W:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:ntfs::boot;
2:106MB:210GB:210GB:ntfs::;
3:210GB:420GB:210GB:ntfs::;
4:420GB:1000GB:581GB:::lba;
6:420GB:428GB:7999MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
7:428GB:639GB:211GB:ext4::;
8:639GB:839GB:200GB:ext4::;
5:839GB:1000GB:161GB:ntfs::;
sdb:8004MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:1049kB:8004MB:8003MB:fat32::boot, lba;
blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________
NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                PARTUUID                            LABEL           PARTLABEL
sda
├─sda1 ntfs     1070B9DC70B9C92C                    9d1cdf6b-01                         System Reserved
├─sda2 ntfs     AE8A64D68A649D19                    9d1cdf6b-02                         Windows
├─sda3 ntfs     007E35F87E35E756                    9d1cdf6b-03                         Chinmay
├─sda4                                              9d1cdf6b-04
├─sda5 ntfs     5802A32E02A30FD4                    9d1cdf6b-05                         New Volume
├─sda6 swap     0e3da262-dfd1-43b4-9d6d-3ab8b8ef2643 9d1cdf6b-06
├─sda7 ext4     399060da-6c03-43ba-aaef-83fc4d9247e4 9d1cdf6b-07
└─sda8 ext4     d42c26c9-4868-4181-946f-e707fb3462aa 9d1cdf6b-08
sdb
└─sdb1 vfat     ECA6-64D6                           001f115e-01                         UBUNTU 24_0
Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________
                    Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1               74.4M  26% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2               109.7G  44% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                   190G   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5               78.8G  48% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda7               140.1G  22% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
/dev/sda8               92.8G  44% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
/dev/sdb1                   1.7G  77% /cdrom
efivarfs                20.2K  80% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________
/dev/sda1               fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2               fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda3               fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5               fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda7               ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda8               ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1               vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
====================== sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
Ubuntu   399060da-6c03-43ba-aaef-83fc4d9247e4
END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware
========================== sda7/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================
 
/ was on /dev/sda7 during installation
/home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
======================= sda7/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
==================== sda7: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
    GiB - GB            File                                Fragment(s)

398.721149445 = 428.123574272  boot/grub/grub.cfg                          1
398.721134186 = 428.123557888  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                  1
447.797092438 = 480.818466816  boot/vmlinuz                                1
450.090972900 = 483.281502208  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-124-generic             1
515.367401123 = 553.371533312  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic               1
447.797092438 = 480.818466816  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic               1
450.090972900 = 483.281502208  boot/vmlinuz.old                            1
411.642574310 = 441.997848576  boot/initrd.img                             5
406.533199310 = 436.511698944  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-124-generic          6
408.861324310 = 439.011504128  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic            5
411.642574310 = 441.997848576  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic            5
406.533199310 = 436.511698944  boot/initrd.img.old                         6
===================== sda7: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom
====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory
==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
    GiB - GB            File                                Fragment(s)
        ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                          1

Best regards,
M K Sundaram

Your sda1 shows system reserved. That is used by Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt drives as unformatted space. Your sda1 should just be a Windows boot partition with boot flag. You have a newer UEFI system, but old BIOS boot installs with very old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Make sure you have both Windows repari/recovery flash drive & Ubuntu live installer as grub only boots working Windows & you may have to temporarily install a Windows boot loader to MBR to boot Windows, make repairs & then restore grub either manually or with Boot-Repair to MBR.

Thanks, @Oldfred. I've decided to get a new SSD and do a clean install of Windows and Ubuntu. The troubleshooting steps were a bit too complex for me, and since I was planning to move the OS to an SSD anyway, this seems like the best approach.
